# Using a Discord bot, how do I get a string of an embed message from another bot

Tags: python, bots, embed, message, discord

I am creating a Discord bot that needs to check all messages to see if a certain string is in an embed message created by any other Discord bot. I know I can use `message.content` to get a string of the message a user has sent but how can I do something similar with bot embeds in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `message.embeds` instead to get the embed string content